# Which of the domains are biholomorphic one to another

Tags: complex-analysis

Given the domains $\mathbb{B}, \mathbb{H}, \mathbb{C^{*}}, \mathbb{C},$ where $\mathbb{B}, \mathbb{H}$ represent the unit circle and the upper half plane, I need to find for each such pair of domains if they are/are not biholomorphic. I suppose that one should provide a map between each of the 6 pairs in case a biholomorphic map exists and if no such map exists then one should provide an explanation why the pair is not biholomorphic. The example $f: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, f(z) = az + b$ would be the one which shows  $f$ is holomorphic and it's inverse also. I do not know how to treat the other pairs. Do you got some hint or a solution proposal ? Many thanks.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb B$ and $\mathbb H$  are biholomorphic to each other. Among $\mathbb B$ (or $\mathbb H$), $\mathbb C^*$ and $\mathbb C$, none is biholomorphic to each other. For the first part, find a Mobius transformation between the two. For the second part, find a property that is preserved by a biholomorphism (such as "Liouville property": "every bounded holomorphic function is constant", or "Cauchy property": "every integral of a holomorphic function on a closed path is zero"), then prove that one of the domains satisfies the property and the other does not.